# WPF 3D light intensity

Tags: wpf, 3d, light, brightness

I have a 3D scene with an AmbientLight. And I want to add a second Light (SpotLight) to beam an area with red. Unfortunately the AmbientLight is much brighter than the Spotlight so it is not visible.

Has anyone an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way to change the intensity of an AmbientLight in WPF is to change the color.  If you want the light to be less intense you just set it to be a darker color (i.e. Gray instead of White or Navy instead of Blue).